# It's different color between real value and value in xib file on iOS

Tags: ios

I have a button made by xib file.
In the xib, the button background color is 0x2d323c of RGB Sliders Hex Color.
I tried build and run simulator then, picked color value using 'Sip' app.
The picked color value is 0x22242e.
And I entered the color value 0x2d323c on the code like below.

```
[self.button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRGB:0x2d323c]];
```

Oh, colorWithRGB: method is in cagetory made by somewone.
Then, the result is returned correct value.
I also tried to check from debugger, po self.button.backgroundColor.
From xib, UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.132649 0.1466 0.178853 1
From code, UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.176471 0.196078 0.235294 1

Is this bug? or what is the problem?

Comment: Try picking the color using Xcode instead. You can do this by customizing a color in the interface builder and select the color picker. Perhaps 'Sip' is using a different color profile.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I've already did that you said.

Answer (score 0):

This could be issue with 'Sip'. I face the same thing while using digital color meter.

Just make sure that while setting the background color from XIB, you are also setting the alpha properly.

After that it's all fine. What ever the color code you mention in the xib is the one which gets reflected on the device screen, don't worry.

Comment: As mentioned before, the alpha property is 1.0f both. Alpha is 1, background is #373d48 RGB Sliders(Opacity 100%), tint is default.

Comment: Did you verify with your designer, that the color that you've set for the button is different from the one mentioned by him?   And pls verify it on a device rather than the simulator.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it. Thank you,